# How do I show a custom google maps icon png in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

Ive designed a custom png icon to be used in google maps which would look like this normally in ruby -

```
<%= image_tag 'icon.svg', class: "imgstar" %>
```

This is what my script looks like to show the location, but I'm really unsure where and how to show the icon I've designed.

```
<% content_for :custom_script do %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var mapStyles = [{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"hue":"#FFBB00"},{"saturation":43.400000000000006},{"lightness":37.599999999999994},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","stylers":[{"hue":"#FFC200"},{"saturation":-61.8},{"lightness":45.599999999999994},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"hue":"#FF0300"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":51.19999999999999},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"hue":"#FF0300"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":52},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"hue":"#0078FF"},{"saturation":-13.200000000000003},{"lightness":2.4000000000000057},{"gamma":1}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"hue":"#00FF6A"},{"saturation":-1.0989010989011234},{"lightness":11.200000000000017},{"gamma":1}]}]
        handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
        handler.buildMap({
        provider: {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @property.address.latitude %>, <%= @property.address.longitude %>),
        styles: mapStyles
        },
        internal: {id: 'map'}
        }, function () {
        handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @location.to_json %>);
        });
        </script>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using the gem `gmaps4rails`. Looking at the [examples](http://apneadiving.github.io/) I would give this a shot:

```
handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @location.to_json %>, picture: {
        url: "<%= image_url 'icon.svg' %>",
        width:  36,
        height: 36
      });
```